# SQL how to remove duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-delete

How can I clean up a table by removing the duplicate records?

```
+----------+--------+------------+
| clientID | status | Insertdate |
+----------+--------+------------+
|        1 | new    |   20191206 |
|        1 | new    |   20191206 |
|        2 | old    |   20191206 |
|        2 | old    |   20191206 |
|        3 | new    |   20191205 |
|        3 | new    |   20191205 |
+----------+--------+------------+
```

I don't have any identity field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: what's your rdbms , oracle,sql-server,mysql?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below query. You can use Row Number.

```
;WITH cte as (
  select clientid
    , status, Insertdate
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by clientid, status, Insertdate order by clientid) RowNumber 
  from Yourtable
) 
delete from cte where RowNumber > 1
```

Comment: ok thanks! with your query i'm able to select only firsts records. How can i delete the others ?

Comment: perform deletion with same query and change the end where to a.RowNumber > 1
use delete query.

Comment: delete
from
(select clientid,
 status, Insertdate
 ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by clientid,status, Insertdate 
 order by clientid ) RowNumber 
 from Yourtable) a
 where a.RowNumber >1 doesn't work ...

Comment: @developerEmiliano  i have edited the query .Please see if it works.
Thanks.

Comment: @developerEmiliano If it solved your problem ,please mark it as an answer so that others can benefit from it too.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help if you are running MySQL database

```
SELECT clientID, status, Insertdate, count(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY clientID, status, Insertdate
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Not only is it not MySQL, but OP has asked how to *delete* duplicate records.

Comment: $limit    = $row["count(*)"] - 1;
 
 mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE clientID='$clientID' AND status='$status' AND Insertdate='$Insertdate' LIMIT $limit");